# Calling a laravel route with optional parameter

Tags: laravel

I have my laravel route like this

```
Route::get('flight/{depdate}/{from}/{to}/{ftype}/{retdate?}/{total}/{class}',
'airlineController@index');
```

In this case when I call this route like this it works

```
http://localhost:8000/flight/2017-09-20/mumbai/delhi/return/2017-09-
20/2/business
```

But when I keep retdate optional while calling lie the below code the route is not found

```
http://localhost:8000/flight/2017-09-20/mumbai/delhi/one-way/2/business
```

what should i do to take care of the optional parameter retdate

thankxx any help will be appreciated

Comment: Simply, add the optional parameters at the end of the URL, e.g. ```Route::get('flight/{depdate}/{from}/{to}/{ftype}/{total}/{class}/{retdate?}',
'airlineController@index');```

Comment: what if i have two optional parameters? just in case

Comment: You can add as many, but just have to take care of the sequence. Or use the POST request that you may easily take care of parameters that are optional or not set.

Comment: You can also pass the optional parameters as query string eg: `<your route>?return=date&your additional optional parameters`

Answer (score 2):

You can use optional parameter

**Optional Parameters**
Occasionally you may need to specify a route parameter, but make the presence of that route parameter optional. You may do so by placing a ? mark after the parameter name. Make sure to give the route's corresponding variable a default value:

```
Route::get('user/{name?}', function ($name = null) {
    return $name;
});

Route::get('user/{name?}', function ($name = 'John') {
    return $name;
});
```

Ref:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

Comment: what if i have tow optional parameters ?  just in case

Comment: you can add fany number  i think

Comment: will it be good to do so ? i mean according to the standards or something

Comment: @SaurabhGupta.as dev said you can sue post .its better choice i think

Comment: i have learnt that to fetch data one should use get but post will also do right theres no harm in it?

Comment: @SaurabhGupta.no there is no harm

Comment: one last question what if i am creating a restful api then also i can use post

Comment: @SaurabhGupta.There is only one diff about rest apis is .rest api will be in json format .nothing else .works same